# How to drop all NOT NULL constraints from a PostgreSQL table in one go

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints, sql-drop, notnull

Is it possible to drop all NOT NULL constraints from a table in one go?

I have a big table with a lot of NOT NULL constraints and I'm searching for a solution that is faster than dropping them separately.

Comment: Try seeing i these links can help you figure out a way to implement this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3370159/how-to-remove-not-null-constraint-in-sql-server-using-query http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2540615/how-can-i-drop-a-not-null-constraint-in-oracle-when-i-dont-know-the-name-of-t

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can group them all in the same alter statement:

```
alter table tbl alter col1 drop not null,
                alter col2 drop not null,
                …
```

---

You can also retrieve the list of relevant columns from the catalog, if you feel like writing a [do block](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-do.html) to generate the needed sql. For instance, something like:

```
select a.attname
  from pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
 where attrelid = 'tbl'::regclass
   and a.attnum > 0
   and not a.attisdropped
   and a.attnotnull;
```

(Note that this will include the primary key-related fields too, so you'll want to filter those out.)

If you do this, don't forget to use `quote_ident()` in the event you ever need to deal with potentially weird characters in column names.

Comment: Your query is great. I've never queried the catalog. Giving the DO block a try will be my next step.

Answer (score 26):

ALTER TABLE table_name ALTER COLUMN column_name [SET NOT NULL| DROP NOT NULL]

Answer (score 10):

If you want to drop all `NOT NULL` constraints in PostreSQL you can use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dropNull(varchar) RETURNS integer AS $$
DECLARE
  columnName varchar(50);
BEGIN

    FOR columnName IN  

select a.attname
  from pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
 where attrelid = $1::regclass
   and a.attnum > 0
   and not a.attisdropped
   and a.attnotnull and a.attname not in(

   SELECT               
  pg_attribute.attname
FROM pg_index, pg_class, pg_attribute 
WHERE 
  pg_class.oid = $1::regclass AND
  indrelid = pg_class.oid AND
  pg_attribute.attrelid = pg_class.oid AND 
  pg_attribute.attnum = any(pg_index.indkey)
  AND indisprimary)

          LOOP
          EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE ' || $1 ||' ALTER COLUMN '||columnName||' DROP NOT NULL';        
        END LOOP;
    RAISE NOTICE 'Done removing the NOT NULL Constraints for TABLE: %', $1;
    RETURN 1;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Please note that the primary keys will be excluded.

Then you can call it using:

> SELECT dropNull(TABLENAME);

Answer (score 7):

#### Preliminaries

Some columns may be required to stay `NOT NULL` by constraints. The only standard case being `PRIMARY KEY` column(s). You may have additional custom constraints. Can be done by checking the system catalog [`pg_constraint`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-constraint.html). See below.

Also note: the code examples below work up to Postgres 15, but changes to system catalogs in future releases may invalidate it (even if unlikely).

#### Proper way

The **clean way only needs regular privileges** to `ALTER` the table. You can automate with dynamic SQL in a `DO` statement (implementing what [Denis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417194/denis-de-bernardy) already suggested):

```sql
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _tbl regclass := 'tbl_b';  -- your table here, schema-qualify if needed!
BEGIN
   RAISE NOTICE '%', (  -- debug mode
   -- EXECUTE (         -- uncomment to automate payload     
      SELECT concat_ws(' '
                     , 'ALTER TABLE'
                     , _tbl
                     , 'ALTER'
                     , string_agg (quote_ident(attname), ' DROP NOT NULL, ALTER ')
                     , 'DROP NOT NULL'
                      )
      FROM   pg_catalog.pg_attribute a
      WHERE  attrelid = _tbl
      AND    attnotnull             -- only NOT NULL columns
      AND    NOT attisdropped       -- exclude dropped columns
      AND    attnum > 0             -- exclude system columns
      AND    NOT EXISTS (           -- exclude PK columns
         SELECT FROM pg_constraint c
         WHERE  c.conrelid = a.attrelid
         AND    c.contype  = 'p'    -- PRIMARY KEY
         AND    a.attnum   = ANY (c.conkey)
         )
      );
END
$do$;
```

Very fast. Does not trigger a table rewrite in modern versions of Postgres.

Execute care with dynamic commands and be wary of SQL injection. I switched this to debug mode, so it only reports the DDL code as `NOTICE`. Have a look.
If your confident, comment the `RAISE NOTICE` line and un-comment `EXECUTE` to prime the bomb.

This is a spin-off from this bigger answer:

- [Generate DEFAULT values in a CTE UPSERT using PostgreSQL 9.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23794405/generate-default-values-in-a-cte-upsert-using-postgresql-9-3/23797357#23797357)

Over there I drop `NOT NULL` constraints from a table created with:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_b (LIKE tbl_a INCLUDING DEFAULTS);
```

Since, [per documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtable.html):

> Not-null constraints are always copied to the new table.

#### Quick and dirty

There is a *quick and dirty way* with **superuser privileges**:

```sql
UPDATE pg_attribute
SET    attnotnull = FALSE
WHERE  attrelid = 'tbl_b'::regclass  -- schema-qualify if needed!
AND    attnotnull          -- only NOT NULL columns
AND    NOT attisdropped    -- exclude dropped columns
AND    attnum > 0          -- exclude system columns
AND    NOT EXISTS (        -- exclude PK columns
   SELECT FROM pg_constraint c
   WHERE  c.conrelid = a.attrelid
   AND    c.contype  = 'p'  -- PRIMARY KEY
   AND    a.attnum   = ANY (c.conkey)
   );
```

The shortcut is tempting. But screw this up, and you may break your database (cluster). The basic rule is: never tamper with system catalogs directly. So not recommended.

Comment: The `DO` block snippet doesn't work because it also contains primary keys that pg refuses to drop.

Comment: @user: The OP asked for *"all NOT NULL constraints"*. Still, to make the answer more universally useful I updated to exempt PK columns.

Answer (score 0):

I had a scenario needing to remove the `NOT NULL` from every field with a certain name across the entire database. Here was my solution. The `where` clause could be modified to handle whatever search pattern you need.

```sql
DO $$ DECLARE row record;
BEGIN FOR row IN 
    (
        SELECT
            table_schema, table_name, column_name
        FROM
            information_schema.columns 
        WHERE
            column_name IN ( 'field1', 'field2' )
    )
    LOOP
        EXECUTE 
          'ALTER TABLE ' || row.table_schema || '.' || row.table_name || ' ALTER '
       || string_agg (quote_ident(row.column_name), ' DROP NOT NULL, ALTER ')
       || ' DROP NOT NULL;';
    END LOOP;
END; $$;
```

piggybacked off some other examples, this worked better for my needs

Answer (score -4):

Yes, it is. I had the same issue..

To resolve, I had to write a C# .net script which traversed all the plSql database and removed all the matching constraints..

For, specific info on how to remove single constraints, pl follow the link. http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/drop.php